# Format Data using panadas groupBy such that it groups by one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have the data in below format in an csv :-

[image]

However, the format in which I required is below :-

[image]

I have written below code, but somehow the groupby is not working for me.

```
def grouping():
    df = pd.read_csv("final_data_6.csv")
    df['n'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['data'], x['Period']), axis=1)
    df.groupby(['data','Period'])['n'].apply(list).reset_index()
    df.to_csv("final_data_9.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Comment: Please do not post images as sample input data.

Comment: Sure, will keep it in mind.

Comment: Actually, I used excel and it got posted as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with create dictionaries filled by list:

```
def grouping():
    df = pd.read_csv("final_data_6.csv")
    
    df['n'] = [x for x in zip(df['positions'], df['Period'])]
    df=df.groupby('data')['n'].agg(lambda x:{'entities':list(x)}).reset_index(name='entity')
    
    df.to_csv("final_data_9.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Sample data test:

```
print (df)
  data positions        Period
0  abc     37,41       disease
1  abc     10,16         drugs
2  def      4,14    indication
3  def     78,86  intervention

df['n'] = [x for x in zip(df['positions'], df['Period'])]
print (df)
  data positions        Period                      n
0  abc     37,41       disease       (37,41, disease)
1  abc     10,16         drugs         (10,16, drugs)
2  def      4,14    indication     (4,14, indication)
3  def     78,86  intervention  (78,86, intervention)


df=df.groupby('data')['n'].agg(lambda x:{'entities':list(x)}).reset_index(name='entity')

print (df)
  data                                             entity
0  abc  {'entities': [('37,41', 'disease'), ('10,16', ...
1  def  {'entities': [('4,14', 'indication'), ('78,86'...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted the answer, but it is still returning the same output. 
{'entities': [('38, 42', '38, 42,disease'), ('5, 15', '5, 15,drugs')]}

Comment: @SourabhRaj - What is `print (df[['data','positions','Period']].head().to_dict())` ? If check my sample data in answer, do you have same ouput?

Comment: Yeah, its same for this as well.
def grouping():
    df = pd.read_csv("final_data_6.csv")
    df['n'] = [x for x in zip(df['positions'], df['Period'])]
    df=df.groupby('data')['n'].agg(lambda x:{'entities':list(x)}).reset_index(name='entity')
    print(df[['data','positions','Period']].head().to_dict())
    # input()

Comment: @SourabhRaj I think what is `print (df[['data','positions','Period']].head().to_dict())` after `df = pd.read_csv("final_data_6.csv")`. For testing why double values `{'entities': [('38, 42', '38, 42,disease'), ('5, 15', '5, 15,drugs')]}`

Comment: The output for that is :
{'data': {0: ‘abc  ', 1: ' abc  ', 2: ‘def’, 3: ' def ‘}, 'positions': {0: '37, 41', 1: '10, 16', 2: '4, 14', 3: '78, 86'}, 'Period': {0: '37, 41,disease', 1: '10, 16,drugs', 2: '4, 14,indication', 3: '78, 86,intervention’}}